# Introduction Window to program pyqt4

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

i have been create an introduction window for my program , but it run with my program , how can i run the introduction window first then after while run my program ?

Answer (score 2):

maybe you're looking for [QSplashScreen](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsplashscreen.html)

EDIT :

```
from time import sleep  

from PyQt4.QtGui import QSplashScreen 

splash = QSplashScreen( ... )
...
splash.show()
sleep(5)
splash.close()
```

Comment: it's work but it show and close quickly how i can keep it long time ??

Comment: It might even be better to use a QTimer.singleShot that will close the window after a certain amount of time, rather than sleeping the main thread. You can create and show the splash, start the timer which will hide the splash and show the main window. and then go into your main event loop with app.exec_()